# facebook Like Button - padding between like button and share button

Tags: html, facebook, css

[image]

I would like to add the padding between like button and share button. How can I add the padding it?

Comment: You can’t – the whole thing is rendered inside an iframe, and you have no access to it whatsoever with CSS. (You could place two social plugins next to each other – one Like button without Share button, and then an extra Share button. But that won’t give you exactly the same layout though.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. I couldn't find any solution.